ubuntu c library import not found after installing with make
I am attemping to use the c wsserver library. After installing with make, when attempting to run the library, it gives me the error
main.c:4:10: fatal error: ws.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <ws.h>
      |          ^~~~~~

the code was ran with the following command:
gcc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib64 -lws main.c

here is the ls for /usr/local/include:
> ls /usr/local/include/
wsserver

and here is the ls for /usr/local/lib64
> ls /usr/local/lib64/
libws.a  pkgconfig

Any idea why?
I expected the library to be imported without problems, but it can not find the library.

Where is ws.h in /usr/local/include?

If wsserver is a subdirectory and ws.h is in there, you need #include <wsserver/ws.h>

Or use -I/usr/local/include/wsserver. The point is that it doesn't search for the header files recursively, only in the specific directories you list.

It's confusing because the wsserver.pc file that gets installed (for use with the pkgconf or pkg-config programs to determine compiler/linker options) sets the include directory to ${prefix}/include rather than ${prefix}/include/wsserver (where ${prefix} is the installation location, e.g. /usr/local), but the example programs use #include <ws.h> rather than #include <wsserver/ws.h>.
